# Converting Grammar to Chomsky Normal Form

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I have to convert a grammar to Chomsky normal form, the grammar is something like this
(not exactly but this is the important bit)

V → W

W → wWxXyYzZ | vXy | xX

X → xYZ | xY | xW | zZ

Y → xX | wW | wV | x

Z → yY | wW | wX | y | ϵ

I add the new start

S → V

V → X

W → wWxXyYzZ | vXy | xX

X → xYZ | xY | xW | zZ

Y → xX | wW | wV | x

Z → yY | wW | wX | y | ϵ

Remove nullables

S → V

V → X

W → wWxXyYzZ | vXy | xX | wWxXyYz

X → xYZ | xY | xW | zZ | xY | z

Y → xX | wW | wV | x

Z → yY | wW | wX | y

Remove unit variables

S → wWxXyYzZ | vXy | xX | wWxXyYz

V → wWxXyYzZ | vXy | xX | wWxXyYz

W → wWxXyYzZ | vXy | xX | wWxXyYz

X → xYZ | xY | xW | zZ | xY | z

Y → xX | wW | wV | x

Z → yY | wW | wX | y

When I am in this situation, It just feels strange to have 3 exactly the same.

I presume I can get rid of V because it can never be reached from the new start? I also take it that W needs to stay because it is referenced in the other variables?

Is there anything more I would need to do or do I move on to adding the variables to reduce everything to a reference to a single terminal or 2 variables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You presume wrong - V is referenced by Y, which is referenced by S.

As far as I can see, you can in fact move on to adding variables now.

Comment: Excellent, well it wasn't supposed to, that was a mistake on my part. I changed the grammar and the variables because it is from a question and I wanted to try to do most of it myself. Thank you for the input though, flippant or not.